# How to convert global to local coordinates in blender 2.5?

Tags: python, blender

I want to move a bone in Blender 2.5 with the following script

```
bpy.context.object.pose.bones['hand_ik.L'].location=(X1,Y1,Z1)
```

but i have the global (X2,Y2,Z2). How can i convert X2,Y2,Z2 (with matrix manipulations) to the corresponding X1,Y1,Z1

I want to achieve the same movement as

```
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(X2,Y2,Z2),const raint_orientation='GLOBAL')
```

I found out that with the following code i can move a parentless bone

```
ob = bpy.context.object 
globalVector = Vector((1.0, 0.0, 0.0))  
mw = bpy.data.armatures['Armature'].bones['hand_IK.R'].matrix.copy()  
bpy.context.object.pose.bones['hand_IK.R'].location = mw.inverted()*globalVector
```

But what to do when a bone has a parent and is not connected?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

A few weeks ago, write access to PoseBose.matrix (The Armature-Space matrix of the bone) was granted to the python API. If you're using 2.59 or the latest trunk, you could use something like this code:

```
from mathutils import Matrix

ob = bpy.context.object 
globalVector = Vector((1.0, 0.0, 0.0))  
mw = bpy.data.armatures['Armature'].bones['hand_IK.R'].matrix.copy()  
obGlobal = ob.matrix_world
bpy.context.object.pose.bones['hand_IK.R'].matrix = ob.matrix_world.inverted()*(Matrix.Translation(globalVector)+mw.to_3x3().to_4x4())
```

the conversion to a dimension of 3 and then back to 4 clears the original translation, and then you add in your globalVector and invert the whole thing to take the object's global matrix under account.

For good code examples of manipulating bones, look at my Blender Addon for Motion Capture, [Here](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-extensions/trunk/py/scripts/addons/mocap/retarget.py), at function bakeTransform in retargetEndUser.